# How do I configure GraphQL servlet endpoint for graphql-java-servlet along with Micronaut Controllers?

Tags: java, servlets, graphql, micronaut, graphql-java

I have got a requirement to implement a File Upload functionality using GraphQL. My current Micronaut project has already some Controller classes and graphql-java-servlet supports file upload, it needs a Servlet to be created. How do I configure the micronaut project for both Controllers and Servlet?

I have tried creating simple servlet from [graphql-java-servlet](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/servlet/getting-started/) in the micronaut project and keeping all my controllers as it is.

````
public class HelloServlet extends GraphQLHttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected GraphQLConfiguration getConfiguration() {
    ...
  }

  private GraphQLSchema createSchema() {
    ...
  }

}```

When I start the Micronaut application. it only identifies controllers and I am able to invoke them using curl request. Unfortunately (@WebServlet) is not configured and not exposed.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micronaut does not support the servlet API, so it is not possible to register a servlet.